# How to connect mysql database with nodejs from google cloud

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a NodeJs application and MySQL database.
I have deployed nodejs application in google cloud and created MySQL database in `google cloud` and connected to nodejs application
i am able deploye the application successfully but application not able to connect to cloud mysql dayabase.

But when i am trying to connect cloud mysql from my local mysql workbench, it's successfully connecting to database. and i am able to connect cloud mysql database from local nodejs application

but i am not able to connect from deployed nodejs application to cloud mysql db

**error** `Database is not connectedError: connect ETIMEDOUT`

**Db.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var properties = PropertiesReader('./db.properties');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    connectionLimit : properties.get('pool'),
    host: properties.get('hostname'),
    user: properties.get('username'),
    password: properties.get('password'),
    database: properties.get('dbname')
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected");
    } else {
        console.log("Database is not connected" + err);
    }
}
);

module.exports = connection;
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

Comment: So there is no error ?

Comment: yes it has error

Comment: Have you added the environment variables and beta_settings section in your app.yaml file as detailed here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-sql#setting_connection_strings_and_adding_a_library?

Answer (score 2):

In your connection configuration for mysql,host does not work on App Engine. You have to use socketPath . socketPath is the path to a unix domain socket to connect to. Socket path must be something like this

`var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  socketPath     : '/cloudsql/my-project-12345:us-central1:mydatabase',
  user      : 'username',
  password  : 'password',
  database  : 'db_name'
});`

It's a similar process if you're using Postgres on GCloud which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749817/cloud-sql-instance-connection-working-locally-but-not-on-app-engine)

Comment: Note - typo on the code. sockePath should be socketPath

Comment: Yeah, Correct. Modified